# how replace my class with .css() jquery

Tags: jquery

i want replace my class with .css() jquery code.

[For sample this is my link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghenaat/PCkXS/45/),

i want use `{.myclass}` instead of `{background:"green"}`

Please help me..

Comment: But that's not what .css() does.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/ this?

Comment: yeah, the right answer here is all the class manipulation methods in jquery.  Why people are downvoting and trying to close I'm not sure.  I think it's a reasonable mistake to look in vain at the `css` method.  I did that when starting out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`addClass` method](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass` method](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/):

```
$(":radio[name='"+name+"']").parent().addClass('myclass');
$(this).parent().removeClass('myclass');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/PCkXS/47/

Answer (score 3):

Your question as stated doesn't apply because jquery deals with classes using [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).  Documentation linked but basically it would work like you'd expect:

```
$('button.toggleThis').toggleClass('.myclass');
$('button.clickOn').addClass('.myclass');
$('button.clickOff').removeClass('.myclass');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('divname').className = 'activeclass';
```

use this to change the cssclass

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PCkXS/48/)**

Use this:

```
$(":radio").click(function(){
var name = $(this).attr("name");
$(":radio[name='"+name+"']").parent().removeClass('myclass')
$(this).parent().addClass('myclass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace with javascript

```
document.getElementById("element").style.background="";
```

Now if you want to set your class

you use like this:

```
document.getElementById("element").setAttribute("class","myclass");
```